# Sound does not play when going to another view controller (iOS)

Tags: ios, audio, playback

On “back to menu” button press there is a sound that should be played, but the sound is not playing because of the navigation to the main view controller. I tried doing this so it waits for the sound before going back, but it doesn’t work, what should I do?

```
if(appDelegate.disabledSoundEffects==0)
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(playButtonSound)
  withObject:NULL waitUntilDone:true];
```

playButtonSound is the method that plays the sound obviously that’s the code for it in case I’m doing something wrong there

```
dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue= dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_sync(dispatchQueue, ^(void){

    NSBundle * mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

    NSString * filePath = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"clickSound"
                                               ofType:@"mp3"];

    NSData * fileData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSError * error= nil;

    self.audioPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:fileData error:&error];

    if(self.audioPlayer!=nil)
        self.audioPlayer.delegate=self;

    [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.audioPlayer play];
});
```

Comment: Instead of allocating AVAudioPlayer within the class. Allocate this in AppDelegate class, then create a method in appdelegate, and call that method from any class button click. This way your sound always plays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Surjeet said "Instead of allocating AVAudioPlayer within the class. Allocate this in AppDelegate class, then create a method in appdelegate, and call that method from any class button click. This way your sound always plays”.